# Why isn't my for loop incrementing and why isn't my splice being changed?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, hashmap

I came across a problem that seemed very straightforward, but as I coded more some of my expected return were not as I expected.

Any help is appreciated. If you do provide any help please explain your approach and how I got stuck.

#### The problem:

> We're given a string and need to see if it can be broken down into words from a dictionary array. For example:
>
> ```
> const str = "applecomputer";
> const dictArr = ["apple", "computer"];
> stringBreakdown(str, dictArr);
> // true
> ```
>
> Assuming that there are no repeats in the dictionary array, can you write a method that will return true if the string can be broken down into words from the array, or false if not?

#### The two test cases:

```
Expect stringBreakdown('crazyrichasians', [ 'crazy', 'rich', 'asians' ]) // to return true

Expect stringBreakdown('lockcombination', [ 'lock', 'combo' ]) // to return false
```

---

#### My code and approach:

- Create a hash map of all the characters in the string
- Create a helper function remove charters from each string in the array
- As I remove the character in the string I will also decrease each time I've seen that letter from the hash map
- If I seen all the letters in that string then I will remove it from the given array
- Lastly, if the given array length is less than 0, return true because I was able to make all of the word or turn false because more words are in the array

```
const stringBreakdown = (str, dictArr)=> {
  let hashDictionary = {};
  let shouldRemoveWord

  for(let x = 0; x <= str.length-1;x++){
    !hashDictionary[str[x]]  ? hashDictionary[str[x]] =1 : hashDictionary[str[x]]+=1
  }

for(let y = 0; y < dictArr.length;y++ ){
  shouldRemoveWord = removeLetters(hashDictionary,dictArr[y]) 
    if(shouldRemoveWord === true){
      dictArr.splice(y,1)
    }
  }
  console.log('dictArr',dictArr)
  return dictArr.length > 0 ? true : false;
}

const removeLetters = (hash,word) =>{
let modifiedWord = word.split('')

for(let k = 0; k < modifiedWord.length;k++){
    if(hash[word[k]]){
     modifiedWord.splice(k,1)
     hash[word[k]]-=1
   }
}
 return modifiedWord.join('').length < 0  ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: too complicated approach. You could really simply get the first word of the string that matches any word in the dict. Remove it, Get the second word (all these operations can be done using `String.indexOf` for example). If any characters remain return false else return true

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go over each word provided in the array then:

Firstly, check if the length of all the words combined together matches with the length of the string under test. If not return `false`.

Secondly, if the length matches, then check whether every word as a whole is included as a sub-string in the supplied string:

```js
function stringBreakdown(str, dictArr){
  return dictArr.join("").length === str.length
         && 
         dictArr.every(word => str.includes(word)); 
}
//tests
console.log(stringBreakdown('crazyrichasians', [ 'crazy', 'rich', 'asians' ]));
console.log(stringBreakdown('lockcombination', [ 'lock', 'combo' ]));
console.log(stringBreakdown('applecomputer', [ 'apple', 'computer']));
console.log(stringBreakdown('appelcomputer', [ 'apple', 'computer']));
console.log(stringBreakdown('appcolemputer', [ 'apple', 'computer']));
console.log(stringBreakdown('applecomputer', [ 'app', 'le', 'computer']));
```

Your approach is dubious as when you go through each character by character you are not looking at the word it forms i.e. in your case if `applecomputer` is the string and the array has ['appel', 'comterpu'] your algorithm will return `true` in this case.

It is because you are making a character map from the inout string `str` and then going through each word's character and decrementing the occurrence of it in the character map so the combination doesn't matter.

```js
const stringBreakdown = (str, dictArr)=> {
  let hashDictionary = {};
  let shouldRemoveWord

  for(let x = 0; x <= str.length-1;x++){
    !hashDictionary[str[x]]  ? hashDictionary[str[x]] =1 : hashDictionary[str[x]]+=1
  }

for(let y = 0; y < dictArr.length;y++ ){
  shouldRemoveWord = removeLetters(hashDictionary,dictArr[y]) 
    if(shouldRemoveWord === true){
      dictArr.splice(y,1)
    }
  }
  return dictArr.length > 0 ? true : false;
}

const removeLetters = (hash,word) =>{
let modifiedWord = word.split('')

for(let k = 0; k < modifiedWord.length;k++){
    if(hash[word[k]]){
     modifiedWord.splice(k,1)
     hash[word[k]]-=1
   }
}
 return modifiedWord.join('').length < 0  ? true : false;
}
//doesn't work outputs true
console.log(stringBreakdown('applecomputer', ['appel', 'computer']));
```

Comment: Loved your explanation, thank you this really helped me understand the approach more

Answer (score 1):

simply loop through the dictionary

```js
const dictArr = ["lock", "combo"];
function checkInDic(val){
    var len = 0;
    dictArr.forEach(element => {
        if(val.includes(element)){
            len += element.length;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    });
    if(len == val.length){
        return true;
    }else{
        return false;
    }
}
```